# symfony2 attach session Id to Url as GET parameter

Tags: symfony

I have the feeling my question is so basic, that I cannot find information on it.

In our symfony2 app we want to attach the sessionId to every Url as GET parameter Like e.g.
http://example.com/blog/?sid=28397497523423irzeuw96ft73rzifr67tw

We want to use it as way to identify users for debugging and also for identifying users, who don't allow cookies on their browser.

How can I achieve this? Is there a Symfony way? Or do I have to develop a class to attach the session? A Listener maybe?

To clarify my question:

1. : I am looking for a central place to have my app always attach the get parameter to each call.
2. : I am looking for the correct place to read it again ( although I guess I will use a Listener I found meanwhile)

We are using Symfony 2.7 on an Apache server.

Comment: I think it's possible with request event listener. But I'd reconsider a few times ``who don't allow cookies on their browser``. How much users have configured their browsers this way?

Comment: enough people to consider it. But we will need it for debugging purposes anyway. You know that situations, when product team comes and says "This user had problems with our app" the sessionId is usually the only way to find out who "this user" is and what he did.

Comment: what about putting the session ID to the logs?

Comment: yes of course there the session id would go in the logs, too. But how would you connect the view of a smartphone browser to the matching log entries? 
I need a parameter in the url to identify the user by. We decided it should be the session id and I am researching a clever way to get it there.

Comment: Don't you afraid it will expose your app to CSRF attack?

Comment: All other parameters are even more dangerous or inefficient in the usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we finally did to get this solved was the following:
We already have a class to extend the Twig functionalities. It resides in the folder ../OurBundle/Twig and is called

```
class CoreExtension extends Twig_Extension implements Twig_Extension_GlobalsInterface {....
```

there we have a method:

```
public function addSession($url)
{
    $sessionId = VisitorHolder::get()->getSessionId();
    $query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
    parse_str($query, $arrQuery);

    if (empty($query)) {
        $url .= '?'.self::OUR_SESSION_ID_VAR_NAME.'='.$sessionId;
    } elseif (!empty($query) && empty($arrQuery[self::GKM_SESSION_ID_VAR_NAME])) {
        $url .= '&'.self::OUR_SESSION_ID_VAR_NAME.'='.$sessionId;
    }

    return $url;
}
```

In the twig files ( and I really hoped to avoid that ) we changed our liks like the following:

```
<p>
    <a loading="1" href="{{ orderlink }}">
        {{ content.getDescription('DE','EN') }}
    </a>
</p>
```

after:

```
<p>
    <a loading="1" href="{{ orderlink | addSessionId }}">
        {{ content.getDescription('DE','EN') }}
    </a>
</p>
```

So you still have to go through all your links in the templates and add it , where an session is needed. The method then checks if the session is already attached or not and will attach it once.

You can also use this extension in another bundle as long as you pass it on there via the services.yml

Hope that helps someone stuck with the same problem.